# Alternative way of getting id based on pressed button of each row?

Tags: php, sql

I'm making a functionality which shows shops in a database in rows with a button behind each shop, and a checkbox in front of each shop. I would like to find another way of getting the id of the shop based on the button pressed. The shop of which the button is selected gets deleted from the database.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM alb_locaties WHERE Verwijderd = '0'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    echo "<form action='' method='get'>";
        echo "<table id='MainTable'>
                    <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Shopnaam</th>
                    <th></th>
                    </tr>";

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $ID = $row['I_id'];
        echo    "<tr>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' name='Shops[]' value='$ID'></td>
                    <td>$ID</td>
                    <input type='hidden' name='givenID' value='$ID'>
                    <td><a href=\"Reset_locatieshops.php?givenID='$ID'\"><input type='button' value='Verwijder'/></a></td>
                </tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<input id='SelectionButton' type='submit' name='SelectionDelete' value='Verwijder selectie'/>";
    echo "</form>";
}

if (isset($_GET['givenID'])){
        $selectedID = $_GET['givenID'];
        // FIRST DELETE
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM alb_locaties INNER JOIN alb_afdelingen ON alb_locaties.I_id = alb_afdelingen.locaties WHERE alb_locaties.I_id = {$selectedID}";
```

Now it's determined by `<a href=\"Reset_locatieshops.php?givenID='$ID'\">` and `$selectedID = $_GET['givenID'];`, but I would rather use a way in which it doesnt show the ID in the URL. Post also seems like a better option, because now when I refresh the page it executes the query again because of the ID in the URL. How can I still get the ID, but by using a different method.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Dharman Yes I know about that, I was planning on implementing that when everything worked properly, thank you anyway

Comment: Why not to use AJAX-based approach without page reloading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I found it. I changed the form method to post,

I changed the `<a href=\"Reset_locatieshops.php?givenID='$ID'\"><input type='button' value='Verwijder'/></a>` to `<input type='submit' value='Verwijder' name='submit'>`.

After that I used `$selectedID = $_POST['givenID'];` to get the ID given to the `<input type='hidden' name='givenID'`

Comment: If someone wanted to see the ID, they still could.